# Qt disconnectNotify() not called on receiver object destruction

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class C that emits a signal S. S may be connected to zero, one ore more receivers (R) (the number of connections varies over time, and connectionsw are made by the receivers).

C needs to do things when then number of listeners to S get more than zero, and to do other things when the number of listeners on S gets back to zero.

I thought that I could use:

```
connectNotify()
```

and

```
disconnectNotify()
```

well,...

What I notice is that the connectNotify() function works well, but the disconnectNotify() is not called (in class C) when the receiving object is destroyed. It is only called when an explicit disconnection, using disconnect(), is used.

Adding an explicit disconnect in the destructor of the listeners was not very successful either: got a segmentation fault when exiting the whole application. (I guess it is not very nice to try to use disconnect() when everything is going down.)

I tried to use the destroy() signal sent from R instances to C when R is destroyed: That works, but how can I be sure that R was connected at destruction time? (The receivers R may exist in non-connected state):

In class C, slot X (called on reception of R's destroyed()), checking QObject::receivers(), seems to return the number of receivers before the destruction is performed. As I don't know whether the object being destroyed was connected or not, I am stuck!

Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same behavior in a test app; this seems inconsistent with the documentation to me.  Your idea to explicitly disconnect in the destructor works for me, but the order of destruction in your program may be messing things up.  I'm curious to know if anyone else can get a `disconnectNotify` when the receiver of a signal is destroyed.

Comment: This is fixed in Qt 5. See [QTBUG-4844](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-4844).

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that all R are destroyed before C, you could manage the connections yourself in the class C:

Header file:

```
#include <QtCore/QSet>

class C : (...)
{
    (...)

public:
    void connectReceiver( QObject* receiver );

private slots:
    void handleReceiverDestruction( QObject* receiver );

private:
    QSet< QObject* > _connectedReceivers;
};
```

Source file:

```
void C::connectReceiver( QObject* receiver  )
{
    // nothing to do if the receiver is already connected
    if( _connectedReceivers.contains( receiver  ) ) return;

    _connectedReceivers.append( receiver )

    connect( ... ); // <- do your connection(s) here
    connect( receiver, SIGNAL( destroyed                ( QObject* ) ), 
             this    , SLOT  ( handleReceiverDestruction( QObject* ) ) );
}

void C::handleReceiverDestruction( QObject* receiver )
{
    if( !_connectedReceivers.contains( receiver ) )
    {
        // if this happens, a receiver R's destroyed() signal was connected to
        // this function altough R is not a receiver of signal X.
        Q_ASSERT( false );
        return;
    }

    disconnect( ... ); // <- one or more might be necessary here

    _connectedReceivers.remove( receiver );
}
```

Hint: I did not test this for compilation or logical errors but you should get the idea.

Personally, I would maybe add the following:

```
C::~C()
{
    if( !_connectedReceivers.isEmpty() )
    {
        // If you land here, a receiver was not (properly) destroyed before this object
        Q_ASSERT( false );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
This is very close to what I tryed to do as a workaround. I am also checking QOBject::receivers() from time to time, as QObject::receivers() seems to be  decremented when a receivers is destroyed (but this happen after receiving the destroyed() signal in C). They are many possible workarounds, but I still feel the behaviour of disconnectNotify is strange,
Thanks again!